# Connect ArangoDB remotely

Tags: arangodb

I try to connect to ArangoDB which located in another server from my PC but seems unsuccessful. I then tried to access it by using the Web UI provided by typing the server ip http://x.x.x.x:8529 but failed too. I tried my luck on the localhost ArangoDB and replace it with my own PC ip address and it doesn't work too. It only works when the ip name is 127.0.0.1 or the name is localhost. May I know how to access arangoDB.

FYI, I have tried the approach here. [Remote javascript interaction with arangodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991902/remote-javascript-interaction-with-arangodb) but cannot get through.

Appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The server by default only opens its ports on 127.0.0.1 and without any authentication.

You can edit the config file "arangod.conf" to change this. Change the line

```
endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:8529
```

to

```
endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529
```

In order to enable authentication you can change

```
disable-authentication = yes
```

to

```
disable-authentication = no
```

Comment: Using command line `arangod --server.endpoint tcp://0.0.0.0:8529`

Comment: thank fceller. "arangod.conf" in ubuntu maybe "/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf"

Comment: config file no longer has disable-authentication. It has authentication, which is true by default.