# Remote ArangoDB access

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to access a remote ArangoDb install (on a windows server).

I've tried changing the endpoint in the arangod.conf as mentioned in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081017/connect-arangodb-remotely) but as soon as I do the database stops responding both remotely and locally.

I would like to be able to do the following remotely:

1. Connect to the server in my application code (during development).
2. Connect to the server from a local arangosh shell.
3. Connect to the Arango server dashboard (http://127.0.0.1:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/standalone.html)

Comment: Did you double-check that the server is bound to `0.0.0.0:8529`? If so, you should be able to access web interface via `127.0.0.1:8529` on the server.

Comment: Yes I can access on the server itself, I want to be able to access from another machine.

Comment: If the remote machine is on the same network, access it via the network IP. If it's over the internet, use the external IP (e.g. http://www.myipaddress.com/). Note that you may have to configure your firewall to allow incoming and outgoing connections. If the server is behind a NAT (e.g. DSL router), you may need to open the port 8529 in addition.

Comment: Sorry,  I should have made it clear that both machines are on the same network. I'm accessing it via the server's IP but am unable to connect.

Comment: is it possible that there is a firewall somewhere, blocking requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long time since I came back to this. Thanks to the previous comments I was able to sort this out.

The file to edit is arangod.conf. On a windows machine located at:

```
C:\Program Files\ArangoDB 2.6.9\etc\arangodb\arangod.conf
```

The comments under the [server] section helped. I changed the endpoint to be the IP address of my server (bottom line)

```
[server]
# Specify the endpoint for HTTP requests by clients.
#  tcp://ipv4-address:port
#  tcp://[ipv6-address]:port
#  ssl://ipv4-address:port
#  ssl://[ipv6-address]:port
#  unix:///path/to/socket
#
# Examples:
#   endpoint = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529
#   endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:8529
#   endpoint = tcp://localhost:8529
#   endpoint = tcp://myserver.arangodb.com:8529
#   endpoint = tcp://[::]:8529
#   endpoint = tcp://[fe80::21a:5df1:aede:98cf]:8529
#

endpoint = tcp://192.168.0.14:8529
```

Now I am able to access the server from my client using the above address.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I am using Docker on Windows and spent hours trying to expose the arango guest container to the host. What works on Linux with strightforward does not work on Windows. (I changed endpoint to = tcp://0.0.0.0:8529)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [managing endpoints](https://docs.arangodb.com/ConfigureArango/Endpoint.html) documentation.It explains how to bind and how to check whether it worked out.